# Mi sitio se cae luego de unos días de activar el AMP

Tags: wordpress, amp

Tengo un sitio en Wordpress con unas 15K visitas diarias, le he instalado el plugin oficial de AMP, pero se cae luego de 2 o 3 días de tener instalado le plugin de AMP y no entiendo porque.

Me pasa con diferentes themes y configuraciones (con o sin plugins) que se les ocurre que pueda ser? para mí parece que llena algo de la base de datos, quiero saber si AMP usa algo en la BD?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué significa que "se cae"? ¿Da algún tipo de mensaje de error? ¿El rendimiento se degrada hasta límites que no carga la web?

Comment: Si, no me da ningún error, solo se pone lenta, lenta y a los 10 minutos de estar lenta, ya no carga, creo que es un conflicto con otro plugin, lo raro es que pasa luego de 2 días

Comment: ¿Sueles vigilar el uso de CPU y memoria de la máquina? ¿Es un alojamiento compartido o administras el servidor?

Comment: Te amplío el significado de mi comentario anterior. La lentitud de una página puede deberse a diferentes factores o cuellos de botella: CPU (existe algún componente que cada vez necesita realizar más cálculos y eso aumenta la latencia), memoria del servidor web (se levantan demasiados procesos de apache o éstos hacen un uso elevado de la memoria, haciendo que el servidor entre en paginación), memoria del servidor MySQL (la caché de claves, datos, etc, comienza a usarse por debajo de su umbral máximo, pero por encima de un uso normal, haciendo que un dimensionamiento previo se quede pequeño).

Comment: Y habría más motivos (en el caso de usar CDNs, reverse proxies, etc), por lo que necesito la mayor información para depurar qué podría estar pasando. ¿Ha mirado en la página de soporte de ese plugin de AMP? Por cierto, no has dicho exactamente cuál es el que estás usando.